# Isn't ReloadState method conflicts with Init on MvxViewModel?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

According to this https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle, we should implement save state and reload state to handle tombstoning.

But what happens if we have a value parameter in the Init method ?

example:

```
public StockDetailViewModel
{
    int stockId;

    ...

    void Init(int stockIdAsIntent)
    {
        stockId = stockIdAsIntent
    }

    protected override void ReloadFromBundle(IMvxBundle state)
    {
        id = int.Parse(state.Data["id"]);
    }

    protected override void SaveStateToBundle(IMvxBundle bundle)
    {
        bundle.Data["id"] = stockId;
    }

    async void Start()
    {
         stockModel = StockService.Get(stockId);
    }

    ...
}
```

Now let say we navigate to a child view model called `StockFormViewModel`.
Doing this the `SaveState` method is called.
Now we open the Form, do our business, then call `this.Close(this);`

If we follow [CIRS](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle#how-viewmodels-are-created-in-v3), first the `Init` will be called, and then the `ReloadState`.

But the `Init` method will fail because we are coming from a child view model, and no intent was given as argument, giving no chance to the `ReloadState` method to kick in and restore the stockId.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I cannot put my finger on it...

Comment: I did not check this myself, but maybe you can overload the Init method. Meaning providing an Init method without parameters, and an Init method with your parameter, and then letting mvx do the work of picking the good one ?

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried it but no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was mixing MVVMCross navigation with parent intent navigation (due to old refactoring of base class).
It makes perfectly sense that these won't work together.

I switch to full MVVMCross navigation, and with this, there are two scenarios:

1. If the view model is still in cache (mvvmcross has a VM cache), it gets the VM from there, and so, when you call close on the "child", none of the initialization methods are called (Init, Reload or Start).
2. If the view model is not in the cache, it will reconstruct the VM and call ReloadState instead of Init.